Does there exist a matrix Bernstein type inequality for weakly dependent random vectors?
When reviewing the literature, I managed to find the following papers, which deduce Bernstein type inequalities for weakly dependent random variables $\mathcal{X} = \{X_1, \cdots X_N\}$ (where weak dependence is defined to mean that the covariance of any collection of R.V.s in $\mathcal{X}$ is sufficiently small).
"An exponential inequality under weak dependence": https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-12/issue-2/An-exponential-inequality-under-weak-dependence/10.3150/bj/1145993977.full
"Probability and moment inequalities for sums of weakly dependent random variables, with applications": https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414906001608
However, I was unable to find any that provide a matrix Bernstein inequality, like the kind in Theorem 1.6.1 of Tropp's "An Introduction to Matrix Concentration Inequalities" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01571) -- all the inequalities provided in Tropp require that the variables are independent.
Currently stuck in my research on bounding the sum of weakly dependent random vectors, so any insight would be deeply, deeply appreciated.
